# When does $n$ and $n+2$ are primes with $n >1$ odd integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, integers

let $n>1$ be an odd integer , i w'd like to know more about distribution of primes then i'm interesting to check enough mathematical conditions to answer my  following question :

**Question:**  When are $n$ and $n+2$ prime numbers with $n >1$ odd integer ?

**EDit:** for instance i find this condition : $(n-1)!$ must be not divisble by $n$ and $n+2$ i have tried with a few integers it seems works but to show it's hard for me

Thank you for any help

Comment: These are known as twin primes. A decent amount is known about them if you search around.

Comment: For [twin primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime).

Comment: It might be more productive to look at $n + 1$, e.g., http://oeis.org/A014574

Comment: The distribution of these is certainly not known. It's not even known if there are infinitely many.